# Rails validation and Rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

I have the following code that gets run when validation from within a validation method.

```
def validate
    if self.limit_reached = true
        self.errors.add('plan', 'limit reached')
        self.account_setting.update_attribute(:email_sent, true)
    end
end
```

However as the validation is failing, this update is being rolled back, how can I prevent this one update from being rolled back

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the rollback? Doesnt make any sense?

Comment: if self.limit_reached = true should probably be if self.limit_reached == true (double equal) - not sure if that fixes your issue but definitely save you some problems down the road

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def validate
  if self.limit_reached
    self.errors.add('plan', 'limit reached')
    @set_email_sent = true
    return false
  end
end

def after_rollback
  if @set_email_sent
    self.account_setting.update_attribute(:email_sent, true)
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!